# How to create a bash script to make directories and specific files inside each directory

Tags: bash

I wrote a bash script trying to generate one directory named after each file inside the directory from which I run the script.

Original directory= /home/agalvez/data//sims/phylip_format

```
sim1.phylip
sim2.phylip
```

Directories to create = sim1 sim2

The contents of these new directories should be a copy of the original file that names the new directory and an extra file called "input". This file should contain the name of the .phylip file as well as the following:

```
"Name of original file"
U
5
Y
/home/agalvez/data/sims/trees/tree_nodenames.txt
```

After that I want to run the following command (sequentially) in all these new directories:

```
phylip dollop < input > screenout
```

My approach is the following one but it is not working:

```
!/bin/bash

for f in *.phylip;
 mkdir /home/agalvez/data/sims/dollop/$f;
 cp $f /home/agalvez/data/sims/dollop/$f;
 cd /home/agalvez/data/sims/dollop/$f;
 echo "$f" | cat > input;
 echo "U" | cat >> input;
 echo "5" | cat >> input;
 echo "Y" | cat >> input;
 echo "/home/agalvez/data/sims/trees/tree_nodenames.txt" | cat >> input;
 phylip dollop < input > screenout;
;done
```

Edit: The error messge looks like this:

```
line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `mkdir'
line 4: ` mkdir /home/agalvez/data/sims/dollop/$f;'
```

FINAL SOLUTION:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in *.phylip; 
 do
 mkdir /home/agalvez/data/sims/dollop/$f;
 cp /home/agalvez/data/sims/phylip_format/$f /home/agalvez/data/sims/dollop/$f;
 cd /home/agalvez/data/sims/dollop/$f;
 echo "$f" | cat > input;
 echo "U" | cat >> input;
 echo "5" | cat >> input;
 echo "Y" | cat >> input;
 echo "/home/agalvez/data/sims/trees/tree_nodenames.txt" | cat >> input;
 phylip dollop < input > screenout;
done
```

Comment: Your attempt is rather clumsy (what's with the gratuitous `cat`s??) but not obviously wrong. Do you get an error message? If not, can you explain in more detail how it's wrong?

Comment: First of all, thanks for replying. I will add the error message to the original question.

Comment: You are lacking a `do` after `for ...;`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I also had to specify an absolute path for the cp command and now it works! I will add my final answer to the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate problem is that you are lacking a `do` at the beginning of the loop body; but you'll want to refactor this code to avoid hardcoding the directory structure etc.

The first line needs to start with literally the two characters `#` and `!` in order to be a valid [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)).

Notice also [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

The `printf` could be replaced with a here document; I like the compactness of `printf` here.

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in *.phylip; do
    mkdir -p dollop/"$f"
    cp "$f" dollop/"$f"
    cd dollop/"$f"
    printf "%s\n" "$f" "U" "5" "Y" \
        "/home/agalvez/data/sims/trees/tree_nodenames.txt" |
    phylip dollop > screenout
   cd ..
done
```

Going forward, try http://shellcheck.net/ for diagnosing many common beginner problems in shell scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a directory named pingping in your ${HOME} folder with files 1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt. You can accomplish that like this. Modify this code to suit your needs.

```
#! /bin/bash

working_directory="${HOME}/pingping/"

cd $working_directory

for f in *.txt
do
    mkdir "${f%%.*}"
    if [ -f "${f%%.*}.txt" ]
    then
        if [ -d "${f%%.*}" ]
        then
            cp ${f%%.*}.txt ${f%%.*}
            echo "Done copying"
            #phylip dollop < input > screenout
            #echo "Succesfully ran the command
        fi
    else
        echo "not found"
    fi

done
```